# How to check missing values from particular column of python pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, csv, missing-data

I have one **dataframe** like below -

```
               time              machine        message
6      2017-08-07 05:24:31,955    solid    qa  : 6502444
20     2017-08-07 05:24:32,024    solid    prod : 6502445
32     2017-08-07 05:24:32,033    solid    qa : 6502445
44     2017-08-07 05:24:32,041    solid    prod : 6502446
56     2017-08-07 05:24:32,055    solid    qa : 6502446
68     2017-08-07 05:24:32,063    solid    prod : 6502447
80     2017-08-07 05:24:32,071    solid    qa : 6502450
92     2017-08-07 05:24:32,079    solid    prod : 6502451
92     2017-08-07 05:24:32,079    solid    qa : 6502452
104    2017-08-07 05:24:32,086    solid    prod : 6502453
116    2017-08-07 05:24:32,094    liquid    qa : 700001
128    2017-08-07 05:24:32,101    liquid    prod : 700004
140    2017-08-07 05:24:32,108    liquid    qa : 700002
152    2017-08-07 05:24:32,115    liquid    prod : 700005
164    2017-08-07 05:24:32,126    liquid    qa : 700007
176    2017-08-07 05:24:32,133    liquid    prod : 700010
188    2017-08-07 05:24:32,140    liquid    qa : 700008
200    2017-08-07 05:24:32,147    liquid    prod : 700011
```

I want to know which numbers are missing in the message column with respect to qa and prod.

**sample example -**

machine columns - solid, In message column **qa : 6502446**. After this row I'm expecting machine column - solid, In message column **qa : 6502447** but it is not available means missing like that 6502448 is also missing. Same for **prod** as well.

I want to generate one output file in csv format which has header like below -

```
machine,message_header,missing_number_size,start,end,start_time,end_time
```

**Detailed Information -**

- **machine** is solid or liquid (in this case i.e. if 3rd one available then that need to take in account).
- **message_header** is available in the message column values. It is fixed either qa or prod.
- **missing_number_size** is the numbers which get missed in between for qa and prod as well.
- **start** is (last available number + 1) before missed from message column.
- **end** is (first available number - 1) after missed from message column.
- **start_time** is last available time before missed from time column.
- **end_time** is first available time after missed from time column.

**Output.csv** will look like this -

```
machine,message_info,missin_number_size,start,end,start_time,end_time
solid,qa,3,6502447,6502449,2017-08-07 05:24:32,055,2017-08-07 05:24:32,071
solid,qa,1,6502451,6502451,2017-08-07 05:24:32,071,2017-08-07 05:24:32,079
solid,prod,3,6502448,6502450,2017-08-07 05:24:32,063,2017-08-07 05:24:32,079
solid,prod,1,6502452,6502452,2017-08-07 05:24:32,079,2017-08-07 05:24:32,086
liquid,qa,4,700003,700006,2017-08-07 05:24:32,108,2017-08-07 05:24:32,126
liquid,prod,4,700006,700009,2017-08-07 05:24:32,115,2017-08-07 05:24:32,133
```

Edit 1- Based on comment to answer what I did?

I did below experiment but its not pandas way. Its taking time to print output result on console. I want pandas ways (fast) -

**Assumption in code** - data is dictionary which contains value as a whole dataframe like above.

```
for key, value in data.iteritems():
    prev_qa_no = 0
    prev_prod_no = 0
    prev_time = ""
    total_count = 0
    flag = False
    qa = value[value['message'].str.contains("qa")]
    prod = value[value['message'].str.contains("prod")]
    qa['qa'] = qa['message'].apply(remove_name)
    del qa['message']
    qa.sort_values('qa',inplace=True)
    for index, row in qa.iterrows():
        time = row['time']
        feed = row['feed']
        qa_no = int(row['qa'])
        if flag:
            if (qa_no - prev_qa_no) > 1:
                diff=qa_no-prev_qa_no+1
                print str(feed.strip())+",qa,"+str(diff)+","+str(prev_qa_no+1)+","+str(qa_no-1)+","+str(prev_time.strip())+","+str(time)

        flag = True
        prev_time = time
        prev_qa_no = qa_no

    prev_time = ""
    total_count = 0
    prod['prod'] = prod['message'].apply(remove_name)
    del prod['message']
    prod.sort_values('prod',inplace=True)
    flag = False
    for index, row in prod.iterrows():
        time = row['time']
        feed = row['feed']
        prod_no = int(row['prod'])
        if flag:
            if (prod_no - prev_prod_no) > 1:
                diff=prod_no-prev_prod_no+1
                print str(feed.strip())+",prod,"+str(diff)+","+str(prev_prod_no+1)+","+str(prod_no-1)+","+str(prev_time.strip())+","+str(time)

        flag = True
        prev_time = time
        prev_prod_no = prod_no
```

Please fill free to ask me if you have any doubt while understanding this question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your dataframe `df` (I reduced to only the message column because I'm lazy):

```
# Stuff to get a similar dataframe####################
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
frame = """message
qa  : 6502444
prod : 6502445
qa : 6502445
prod : 6502446
qa : 6502446
prod : 6502447"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(frame),header=0)
# Stuff to get a similar dataframe END################
#split the message
df2=df['message'].apply(lambda m : m.split(' : '))
#group by message type (qa or prod)
df = pd.DataFrame(df2.tolist(),columns=['prodqa','message'])
gb = df.groupby('prodqa')
qa = gb.get_group('qa')
prod = gb.get_group('prod')
```

You can know check what is missing in qa and in prod.

I haven't fully understand how you want to do that, but if it is to see if each "qa" match a "prod", you can apply set functions, e.g. if you want to see what is in prod and not in qa:

```
missing_in_qa=prod['message'][~prod['message'].isin(qa['message'])]
```

Comment: @Wli- You didn't get the question yet. I don't want to find missing data which is available in prod and not available in qa or vice versa. I want to find missing data of individual (qa and prod). Please see Output.csv to understand it better.

Comment: Well I believe the first part of my answer can still help. You need to work on the dataframes I called qa and prod. You might also need to group by machines (df.groupby('machine'))